# Framework7 js Bundle disables the ajax Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html-framework-7

I am trying to migrate my app from plain HTML to framework 7, everything was going well until I noticed that the ajax requests were not being executed since they resulted in an error

```
Uncaught TypeError: $.ajax is not a function
    at functionName (file.js:73:5)
    at functionName (file.js:69:2)
    at HTMLFormElement.<anonymous> (file.js:18:2)
```

I briefly know that the type error could occur mainly if jquery is not present in the project or when the slim version of Jquery is used which wasn't the case for my project

after some time hunting the cause of the issue, I found that whenever the file `framework7-bundle.min.js` is included ajax would stop working resulting in the above error, and would work if vice versa, is there a way to navigate through this issue?

Answer (score 0):

after some trying to figure out the issue, I found that framework7 comes with its own Dom manipulator and uses the very symbol that jquery uses hence overriding all included jquery functionalities to fix this issue, I did comment on the line from where this Dom Manipulator is initialized.

The Dom Handler can be disabled by removing or commenting on the first line in app.js, this particular line `var $ = Dom7;`